# Console application fails after updating to Serilog 7

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, logging, serilog

My console application has been working fine. Recently, I made some changes and redeployed it, and now it's throwing an exception.

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: No Serilog:Using configuration section is defined and no Serilog assemblies were found. This is most likely because the application is published as a single-file.

[image]

None of my changes were related to Serilog or logging. However, I did update all NuGet packages, including updating *Serilog.AspNetCore* from *6.1.0* to *7.0.0*.

While it's true I have the *Produce single file* option checked, this options was working and I'd prefer to keep using it.

Does anyone know what might have changed in Serilog version 7 that could cause this?

I'm using .NET 7.0. Here's my configuration:

```cs
// Configure Serilog
string logFormat = "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt}][{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}";
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(appServices.Configuration)
    .WriteTo.Console(LogEventLevel.Verbose, logFormat)
    .WriteTo.File(LogFile, LogEventLevel.Verbose, logFormat)
    .WriteTo.List(LogEvents)
    .CreateLogger();
```

And here's my configuration section.

```
"Serilog": {
  "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "System": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what is your target framework (in your csproj)

Comment: @granadaCoder: .NET 7.

Comment: Did you try clean and rebuild in visual studio? Which nuget packages and version number are you using?

Comment: @Dan: Yes, I did do a clean. Unfortunately, when I produce a single file, I cannot easily see what package versions are installed. But I built it without setting that option and could I had the right version (and it seemed to work).

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a bug in Serilog 7, as discussed on [GitHub](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/issues/394).